# Member variables of a object get overridden when creating another object in the object

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have a memory issue with a class of mine.  The issue occurs when I create an object in a member function of a class. It is about the class below. I removed the member functions because they aren’t necessary:

```
class User
{
private:
    bool locked;
    bool active;

    std::vector<City> * userCitys;
    UserData userData;
    Credentials credentials;
```

The problem occurs when I call this function:

```
int User::addCity(CityData cityData) 
{
    lockUserObject(); //Everything is fine here

    City cityToAdd; //When this object is created, the memory of userCitys will get overridden
    cityToAdd.activate();
    userCitys->push_back(cityToAdd);
    int cityID = userCitys->size() - 1;

    userCitys->at(cityID).editCityData(cityData);

    unlockUserObject();
    return cityID;
}
```

In the first place I created userCitys on the stack. For test purpose I placed it on the Heap. The address of userCitys get overridden by some data. I can’t find the problem. the City is just a basic class:

Part of the header:

```
class City
{
private:
    bool active;
    Supplies supplies;
    std::vector<Building> buildings;
    std::vector<Company> companies;
    std::vector<Share> shares;
    std::vector<Troop> troops;
    CityData cityData;
```

Constructor:

```
City::City()
{
    active = false; 
}
```

How is it possible that userCitys get overridden? This all happens on a single Thread so that can’t be a problem. I tried a lot of thing, but I can’t get it to work. What is the best approach to find the problem?

**Edit:**
Lock function:

```
void User::lockUserObject()
{
    for( int i = 0; locked ; i++)
    {
        crossSleep(Settings::userLockSleepInterval);

        if( i >= Settings::userLockMaxTimes )
            Error::addError("User lock is over userLockMaxTimes",2);
    }

    locked = true;
}
```

I call the code here (Test function):

```
City * addCity(User * user)
{
    Location location;
    location.x = 0;
    location.y = 1;

    CityData citydata;
    citydata.location = location;
    citydata.villagers = 0;
    citydata.cityName = "test city";

    int cityID = user->addCity(citydata); //addCity is called here
    City * city = user->cityAction(cityID);;

    if( city == NULL)
        Error::addError("Could not create a city",2);

    return city;
}
```

The add user (Test code):

```
User * addUser()
{
    UserData test;
    test.name = "testtest";
    Credentials testc("testtest",3);

    //Create object user
    int userID = UserControle::addUser(test,testc);
    User * user = UserControle::UserAction(userID);

    if( user == NULL)
        Error::addError("Could not create a user",2);

    return user;
}
```

My test function:

```
void testCode()
{
    User * user = addUser();
    City * city = addCity(user);
}
```

This function in called in main:

```
int main()
{
    testCode();
    return 0;
}
```

Here are UserAction and addUser in UserControle:

```
int UserControle::addUser(UserData userdata, Credentials credentials)
{
    int insertID = -1;
    for( int i = 0; i < (int)UserControle::users.size(); i++)
    {
        if( !UserControle::users.at(i).isActive() )
        {
            insertID = i;
            break;
        }   
    }

    User userToInsert(userdata,credentials);

    if( insertID != -1 )
    {
        UserControle::users.insert( UserControle::users.begin() + insertID,userToInsert);
        return insertID;
    }
    else
    {
        UserControle::users.push_back(userToInsert);
        return UserControle::users.size() - 1;
    }
}

User* UserControle::UserAction(int userID) //check all indexes if greater then 0!
{
    if( (int)UserControle::users.size() <= userID )
    {
        Error::addError("UserAction is out of range",3);
        return NULL;
    }

    if( !UserControle::users.at(userID).isActive())
    {
        Error::addError("UserAction, the user is not active.",3);
        return NULL;
    }

    return &UserControle::users[userID];
}
```

Comment: I think the comment "everything is fine here" looks suspicious, since the first instruction after that causes troubles with memory... what is in there?

Comment: oh and I am assuming you rebuilt everything and are debugging the Debug build and not the Release build, is this the case?

Comment: It's in Debug mode, but I try a rebuild.

Comment: also please supply the code for `lockUserObject()`

Comment: More than the code for `lockUserObject()`, I'd be interested in seeing the code for all the constructors, assignment operator and destructor of `User` class.

Comment: @Dagob: i really don't think that function does what you expect. where does "locked" get set in the for cycle? is it `false` before you enter the function? and if it is `true`, how does it get set to `false` if there is just one thread?

Comment: It gets unlocked in "unlockUserObject();". The end of lockUserObject lockes the object. The locked boolean is a part of the user class.

Comment: @Dagob: also, can you show the code from which you are calling `addCity()`? Aren't you by any chance calling that function through an invalid (NULL or dangling) pointer?

Comment: Instead of this, userCitys->at(cityID).editCityData(cityData);

try creating a temp City refernce and assign the return value from userCitys->at(cityID), and view the object in a debugger.

Comment: @Andy Prowl added. One moment, that is not the correct part.

Comment: @Dagob: not enough (or not clear). i see `addCity()` is a member function of `User` but you call `addCity(user)`. is that another function? does `addUser()` in `testCode()` return a valid and non-NULL pointer?

Comment: @Dagob: ok, now we only miss `addUser()` :)

Comment: @Andy Prowl Updated it again. addUser() in testCode() returns a valid object. The city size is 0. When the code runes "City cityToAdd in User::addCity the city size is over 30.000.000;

Comment: @Leor A That code doesn't get executed. Before that code the userCitys object is corrupted.

Comment: @Dagob: so we're not there yet: how about `UserControle::addUser()` and `UserControl::UserAction()`?

Comment: @Andy Prowl Added, thanks for your time btw.

Comment: @Dagob: there are definitely a couple of problems with those two functions. i have to leave for some time now, i will write an answer when i'm back (if nobody will precede me)

Comment: Thank you very much! Then I will check for your answer later.

Comment: @Dagob: I'm afraid the problem I found is not the one that gives you troubles with the memory. the problem is that you should not return the address of an object stored in a vector. you should store pointers (better if smart pointers) to `User` objects in your vector, and return them. This is because when you insert objects in a vector the vector might move the objects which are already present in a larger memory block if it is needed to extend the vector's capacity. and if you store a pointer to a moved object you have a dangling pointer. but in your case you just add one user... don't know

Comment: @Andy Prowl Thanks for the information, going to change that. I forgot that they create a whole new array on the heap when the size increases. But I also get other strange problems. For example, XXX = new XXXX(); doesn’t create an object on the location of XXX.  Maybe it's just something with my pc. Going to try a reboot. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Reboot didn't work. Going to debug this later. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @Andy Prowl I found another strange thing: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6RIZUx4Mm0&feature=youtu.be. Is it me, or isn't this ride..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you could try:

- Remove code until the fault goes away. In other words, distill a minimal example from your code. I guess you'll then see the error yourself, otherwise post that small example program here and others will.
- Don't use raw pointers. The question with those is always who owns what they point to. Use smart pointers instead, e.g. unique_ptr (C++11) or auto_ptr (C++98) for exclusive ownership.
- If you have pointer members like "userCities", you need to think about what happens when copying instances of that class (you already wrote a proper destructor, or?). So, either prevent copying (make copy-constructor and assignment operator private and without implementing it) or implement them in a way that the vectors are properly cloned and not shared between different instances.
- Don't use C-style casts. If those are necessary to get anything through the compiler, the code is probably broken.